# How can I get even steps on x and y axes in a plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm plotting the shortest distance from a point to a line using the following code

```
Show[Plot[1/2 x + 1/2, {x, -6, 7}], 
     ListPlot[{{4, -2.5}, {2, 1.5}}, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]]
```

As this is the shortest line from the point to the line, the angle between the two lines should be 90 degrees. It doesn't show up like that in *Mathematica*, however, since the y-axis is incrementing in visually smaller steps than the x-axis.

How can I get *Mathematica* to automatically to use even steps on the two axes?

Comment: Look up `AspectRatio`.

Comment: I'm aware of `AspectRatio`, but it's not what I'm looking for. AspectRatio simply stretches the graphics but I'm fine with it's current size.

Comment: Even if you set `AspectRatio -> Automatic`?

Comment: You are absolutely right! `Automatic` does indeed work!

Comment: Read up on what that option does, and then you can write an answer to your own question. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To understand what is going on lets examine your initial plot. We assign it to the variable `g`:

```
g = Show[
       Plot[1/2 x + 1/2, {x, -6, 7}], 
       ListPlot[{{4, -2.5}, {2, 1.5}}, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
    ]
```

[image]

```
g // ImageDimensions
```

> {360, 224}

The figure's aspect ratio is therefore:

```
#2/#1 & @@ ImageDimensions[g] // N
```

> 0.6222222222

which happens to be close to $\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}+1}\approx 0.6180339887$ or the reciprocal of the golden ratio. This ratio is widely considered as being aesthetically pleasing and is therefore the default aspect ratio for Mathematica's `Plot` function:

```
Options[Plot, AspectRatio]
```

> {AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio}

With `AspectRatio->Automatic` Mathematica sets the aspect ratio to the ratio of the plot ranges in x and y directions:

```
h = Show[
      Plot[1/2 x + 1/2, {x, -6, 7}], 
      ListPlot[{{4, -2.5}, {2, 1.5}}, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic],     
      AspectRatio -> Automatic
    ];

#2/#1 & @@ ImageDimensions[h] // N
```

> 0.5083333333

```
#2/#1 & @@ (Subtract @@@ PlotRange[h])
```

> 0.4999999796

(small difference caused by the discrete pixel size).

This choice causes the the plot space to be isotropic which is needed for a correct display of angles.

```
h
```

[image]

Note that the default aspect ratio for `Graphics` is:

```
Options[Graphics, AspectRatio]
```

> {AspectRatio -> Automatic}

This makes sense as in most drawings we want an isotropic space.

Comment: Crystal clear answer, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 8):

This is really a comment, but it doesn't fit well into a comment box.

Since you say in your profile that you are a fan of minimalism, you might want to consider doing your plot this way:

```
Plot[1/2 x + 1/2, {x, -6, 7}, 
  Epilog -> Line[{{4, -2.5}, {2, 1.5}}], 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Sure! That's definitely a better way to do it.